# Having Issues Constraining a UIButton Over a UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, tablefooterview

I have a table view (in a list style app) with an add button pinned to the bottom. The list can be sorted by a number of methods which will rearrange items and add or remove section headers based on the user's choices. Fairly standard stuff.

However, I recently tried to add a footer to the tableview to create a buffer so the last items in the list don't appear behind the add button. Even though the button visually doesn't move I can only tap it if it is appearing over the tableview. It stops working when it is scrolled to the bottom and is over the footer (as it appears in the attached pic.

The button is set up as follow and called in viewDidLoad:

```
func setupAddToListButton() {
    tableView.addSubview(addToListButton)
    addToListButton.addSubview(buttonBackground)
    addToListButton.sendSubviewToBack(buttonBackground)
    tableView.bringSubviewToFront(addToListButton)
    addToListButton.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let buttonColor = activeColor?.color ?? UIColor(named: "CSSpaceGray")
    addToListButton.imageView?.tintColor = buttonColor?.darker()
    let widthConstant = tableView.frame.width / 2
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        addToListButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor, constant:  -40),
        addToListButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor, constant: 40),
        addToListButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        addToListButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -80),
        buttonBackground.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addToListButton.centerXAnchor),
        buttonBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addToListButton.centerYAnchor),
        buttonBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        buttonBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
    ])
}
```

The footer is added in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
 let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.width, height: 100))
 tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

I also tried adding it to the tableView delegate though as follows but still had the same issue:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1 else {
        return nil
    }
    let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.width, height: 100))
    return footer
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    guard section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1 else {
        return 0
    }
    return 100
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? It almost seems as though the gesture recognizers are shifting away with the scrolling tableView. The Issues completely goes away if I don't add the footer.

[image: Button over footer is when it stops being tapable.]

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was able to fix this by updating the `setupAddToListButton()` function and change every where I had `tableView` to `self.parent?.view` instead!

```
func setupAddToListButton() {
    guard let parentView = self.parent?.view else {
        return
    }
    parentView.addSubview(addToListButton)
    addToListButton.addSubview(buttonBackground)
    addToListButton.sendSubviewToBack(buttonBackground)
    parentView.bringSubviewToFront(addToListButton)
    addToListButton.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let buttonColor = activeColor?.color ?? UIColor(named: "CSSpaceGray")
    addToListButton.imageView?.tintColor = buttonColor?.darker()
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        addToListButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor, constant:  -40),
        addToListButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor, constant: 40),
        addToListButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        addToListButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -80),
        buttonBackground.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addToListButton.centerXAnchor),
        buttonBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addToListButton.centerYAnchor),
        buttonBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        buttonBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
    ])
}
```